# Series of functions, limits and integrals

Tags: integration, limits

i'm trying to evaluate the following:
$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n$ and $\int_{0}^{1}f_n$ where $f_n(x) = nX_{(0,1/n)}(x)$ 
and $X_I(x)$= 1 when x belongs to I ,and 0 when x doesn't belong to I. My question is: when i think about these terms, do i ignore the x? in other words, do i freeze it and look and the n?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When finding the pointwise limit, you should consider the function's behavior at a fixed $x$ as $n$ goes to infinity. Since the integral is definite, it is already independent of $x$, so you only need to consider $n$.